# Preserve a '+' symbol in a URL variable

Tags: php, urlencode

I am working with a SOAP feed at the moment that requires the passing of some special variables (pulled from another feed)

eg.

```
+blPsNeYyjvRQhCiHQEISg==
```

It is absolutely vital that the variable be posted exactly as is, but when I am rendering it within a PHP script.. it is treating the `+` symbol as a `+` action and stripping it and trying to perform the calculation

So if I had `blPsNeYyj+vRQhCiHQEISg==` the string is posted as `blPsNeYyj + vRQhCiHQEISg` and causes errors.

If I replace the `+` with `%2b` it works, so I tried URL encode, and it still fails. This is because the `==` at the end has to stay as `==`

So in summary I need all instances of `+` replaced by `%2b`

I have tried

```
$service = preg_replace("/\+/","%2B",$service);
```

but this also fails and just returns `NULL`

ANSWER :

Kept it simple to illustrate the process but to get the feed to work properly I had to use a very bizarre process

```
$service = (urlencode($_REQUEST['service']));

$service = substr($service,0,-6);

$service = $service.'==';
```

Encode it to preserve the + but this then converted the '=' to %3d which stopped the SOAP feed working.

Remove the %3d%3d

Readd two '==' and submit

and it works...

Go figure..

Comment: Try `preg_replace('/\+/', …);`. The plus symbol is a quantifier in regular expressions.

Comment: I've amended my post, try ('/\\+/');

Comment: There is a difference between single quotes and double quotes. If you use double quotes, you have to escape the backslash as well: `"/\\+/"` or `'/\+/'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need urlencode() it:

```
$service = urlencode($service);
```

Build your url

```
$url = "http://.....?service=".$service;
```

and when receiving it:

```
$service = urldecode($_GET['service']);
```

Comment: I used parts of this to get the answer

Answer (score 1):

Your regex was almost correct

This occurs because the + character is used as an expression/a quantifier in the above regular expression, so you have to escape it with a backslash\

This works on my server

```
<?php

$sub = '+blPsNeYyjvRQhCiHQEISg==';

echo preg_replace('/\\+/', '%2b', $sub);
```

outputting

```
%2bblPsNeYyjvRQhCiHQEISg==
```

Comment: OP edited the post, and now it shows an escaped pattern

Comment: I've amended my post - I've tested the above myself, you can also test here

https://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html with pattern /\+/, replacement x, subject y...

Comment: You can use a single backslash in your regex, as in `'/\+/'`, see the [PHP manual on strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but for whatever reason this still left the + out, though due to the stupid feed and how it works no doubt. Fix added to my OP